# Puppet - Escaping YAML variables for Hiera

Tags: escaping, puppet, hiera

I have a pretty simple requirement, but I've tried every escape sequence I can think of, but can't get the output needed.

I need to litterally output into a file:

```
%{VAR}
```

Here's my YAML file:

```
myclass::outputstuff:
    - Heres a litteral var %{VAR}
    - Heres something else %{SOMETHING}
```

And my template.erb:

```
<%= @outputstuff.each do | ostuff | -%>
<%= ostuff -%>
<% end -%>
```

But it like this, it outputs:

```
Heres a litteral var
Heres something else
```

If I add a percent sign like `%%{VAR}`, as advised by other posts, it outputs:

```
Heres a litteral var %
Heres something else %
```

If I add a backslash like `%\{VAR}` it outputs:

```
Heres a litteral var %\{VAR}
Heres something else %\{SOMETHING}
```

I need this lol:

```
Heres a litteral var %{VAR}
Heres something else %{SOMETHING}
```

Comment: Which version of Hiera are you using?

Comment: I was rather unamused to find this little gem in PuppetLabs ticket system: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/HI-127

Comment: @Magellan I thought you was on about a ticket I posted then Lol ... Yeah that ticket got closed pretty promptly ... The answer I've accepted is the good work around

Comment: Agreed. The other answer presented doesn't work for Hiera 1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I managed to get this to work, was this hacky way, found [here](https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16235)

Basically I changed the template.erb to:

```
    <%- @oupputstuff.each do | ostuff | -%>
    <%- if ostuff -%>
    <%= ostuff.gsub(/___/, '%') %>
    <%- end -%>
    <%- end -%>
```

And then in the YAML file:

```
myclass::outputstuff:
    - Heres a litteral var ___{VAR}
    - Heres something else ___{SOMETHING}
```

Very surprising none of the normal escape sequences work Lol

Answer (score 6):

With Hiera 3.3.1 you can use this in your YAML:

```
%%{}{EXAMPLE}
```

Which will output this literal:

```
%{EXAMPLE}
```

Answer (score 2):

From v2.0.0 on, there is the `literal` function, which is the more 'proper' way to do it:

```
%{literal('%')}{VAR}
```

Comment: None of these methods work ... I've upgraded to hiera version 3 now, and still nothing. `%{literal('%')}{VAR}` outputs `{VAR}` ... `%%{}{VAR}` and `%%{FOO}{VAR}` output nothing.

Comment: I had to go to Puppet 3.5.1. Hiera upgrades alone were insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to represent the literal `%{VAR}` string that worked across both Hiera 1.x and 2.x, so that nothing broke while I was mid-upgrade.

Here's the dumb trick I came up with, which worked for me in both 1.3.4 and 2.0.0:

```
---
"%": "%"

myclass::outputstuff:
  - "Heres a literal var %{hiera('%')}{VAR}"
```

After interpolation -- in either Hiera version -- this evaluates to:

```
{"%":"%","myclass::outputstuff":["Heres a literal var %{VAR}"]}
```

Of course this results in that extra `%` key floating around, but that doesn't do any harm. Then, post-upgrade I can switch to `%{literal('%')}`, and remove the extra YAML entry.